# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden asp.net 5 & MVC 6 iis10

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, http-status-code-403, asp.net-core-mvc

I know this question has been asked and answered a few time but those questions are slightly different and the answers to those questions do not resolve my issue.

I have a asp.net 5 & MVC 6 application that works fine in IIS Express and self hosted in WEB. However when I publish to a folder and point IIS at the wwwroot folder I get the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error.

I have tried IISReset and I do have a default root.

Comment: The error goes away if I add a default document which makes it look like requests are not being routed through ASP.net.

Comment: Do you have .net installed and asp.net registered on the server with IIS?

Comment: The server currently serves up .net 4.5.1  sites just fine, but it does feel like iis doesn't know about .net 5.0

Comment: IIS doesn't _need_ to know what framework you're using in your project. It's the AspNet.Loader.dll's job to figure out which framework to load.  Do you have the app pool set to 4.0?

Comment: Right OK that makes sense, Yes the App pool is set to v4.0.

Comment: Hmm ok. Could you attach an mcve?

Comment: In your wwwroot\bin folder there should be the AspNet.Loader.dll file - do you have it there?

Comment: Yes there is an AspNet.Loader there. I get this with a default project but can upload the source.

Comment: Seems a permission issue. In IIS the application you created should be linked to an application pool. Go to that selected application pool and in Actions select Advanced Settings. Under Process Model->Identity change it to LocalSystem. You should then get another error but you'll at least have gotten further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirements

- Windows 7 or better
- Windows Server 2008 R2 or better
- Have IIS installed

#### Procedure

First, make sure you have the HTTP Platform Handler installed in your IIS ([x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690722) / [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=690721)).

Publish your application to the file system and take the content of the `\artifacts\bin\MyWebApp\Release\Publish` folder and copy it into your IIS Server.

When configuring your application, target the `wwwroot` folder that you copied over.

Now you'll need to unlock the `system.webServer/handlers` section which can be found in IIS Manager on the server node under `Configuration Editor`. Search for the right section and unlock it from the right action pane.

Make sure that the App Pool is set to `No Managed Code`. DNX is being run as an external process. IIS doesn't need to know about what it's currently running.

Finally, create a `web.config` with the following content:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It should be running at that point.

---

[Source](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html)

Comment: Thanks as soon as I have fixed my migration issue and can run my project I will give it a try!

Comment: +1. Solved after installing `httpPlatformHandler` on server and setting Site Physical Path to `.../wwwroot` (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, MVC 6)